# Imac 2017 UBUNTU 20.04 no sound from internal speakers

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have been a Mac user for many years and am recently getting interested in Linux
I have been able to install Ubuntu on an old MacBook and it works fine

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 on an external SSD on my iMac 2017 27'' and no sound.

Unfortunately like with all the other distros that I have tried, the internal speakers will not work,
I have tried everything in the book/internet options imac27/alsamixer/pulseaudio etc etc and nothing

My bluetooth headphones work fine.
The strange thing is that alsamixer recognizes my CIRUS audio card/ATI HDMI ( that I don't use )  and when I run some video the sound sliders move, I've tried a lot of internet fixes and just nothing.

So if there is a kind developer or Ubuntu savvy that can give me a hand it'll be much appreciated.

Comment: Is this question very different from your previous one [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1242389/248158)?

Comment: Got a very similar if not the same problem here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1246511/ubuntu-and-other-distributions-no-sound-on-ssd-on-hdd-is-ok